# ubuntu 14.04 how to set all user with same themes?

Tags: themes

This maybe a duplicated question, but I have search around and couldn't find my answer, or maybe I don't know the "terms" of this workaround, which is:

If I have more than 1 user in my system, and I want all user having the same themes and desktop environment, how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the `/etc/skel`

Make a user then apply all configuration you want to do. Then easily copy this configuration from your home to the /etc/skel.

So for now every new user will have the same settings of the firs main user.

Comment: which file should i copy from my home?

Comment: related to your needs. But general directories `.config` `.gconf` `.local` etc... you have to identicate what you want

Comment: like exactly the main account themes, desktop settings and behaviour?

Comment: yes copy these dirs above from your home to /etc/skel

Comment: nope, is not working...

Comment: This answer forgets to explain how `/etc/skel` works. If you add something to `/etc/skel` it will be copied to the home directories of every NEW user created after modifying `/etc/skel`. Adding files to `/etc/skel` will not change the home directories of already created users.